# Native library for tomcat bootstrap loader

Tags: tomcat, java-native-interface, java, bootstrapping

I've instrumented Java.lang.System with a custom method that calls some native code. I use bootclasspath to have this class found by Java's boot strap and I place the native library in jdk's lib path. This works perfectly fine for a normal Java app but I'd like this to run under tomcat.

I've placed the library in both jdk's lib and tomcat's shared/lib but it doesn't seem to work. I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library already loaded in another classloader. Not sure if tomcat uses it's own bootstrap loader.

In any case, how do I get my own native library for a bootstrap class (rt.jar) to load with tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

The `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable can be used to specify any JVM parameters.  Use the same parameters you used for you normal java apps in this environment variable and Tomcat should pick them up.  Keep the native libs out of Tomcat's path so they are not picked up more than once.

Comment: 'Keep the native libs out of Tomcat's path'... Could you elaborate on this? Also, I'm not sure if the library is even loaded once because the method call to the native also fails with an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: @manu1001 I was thinking more of JARs than native libs when keeping right out of Tomcat's directories.  What JVM parameters are you using to load the native library with the standalone Java apps?  

Setting the java.library.path system property via JAVA_HOME with -Djava.library.path=<path to your native libs> might work.

Comment: setting java.library.path won't work because this library is loaded by a bootstrap class. java uses sun.boot.class.path to load natives for bootstrap classes; but that can't be set because of [this issue.](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4285197) So I placed the lib in the already defined boot.class.path which worked for standalone java but not tomcat.